# How can I start Tomcat 8 using ANT

Tags: ant, tomcat8

I upgraded tomcat from 6 to version 8. Now my ant scripts stopped working.

I used to start tomcat 6 using following target:

```
<target name="start-server">
    <java jar="${server.home}/bin/bootstrap.jar" fork="true" spawn="true">
            <jvmarg line="-Dcatalina.home=${server.home} -Dcatalina.base=${server.home}"/>
        </java>
</target>
```

This doesn't work any more.

Comment: Please take a look at [this](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/AntDeploy), I think this information is up-to-date and applicable to tomcat 8 as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use startup.bat or catalina.bat instead of starting it via Java.

```
<exec dir="${server.home}/bin" executable="cmd">
        <arg value="/c"/>
        <arg line="catalina.bat"/>
        <arg line="start"/>
        <env key="CATALINA_HOME" value="${server.home}"/>
        <env key="JAVA_OPTS" value="-Xms256m -Xmx1024m"/>
</exec>
```